# Список из файла

Tags: python, list, ос

Нужно создать список, генерируемый из содержания N текстовых файлов.

`text = []`

Я открываю N текстовый файл и записываю его название в список text.append(название_файла), а теперь нужно в `text['название_файла']` вложить по строке из этого файла в виде переменных.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: я так и не понял что ты имел ввиду...

Comment: Может быть карта нужна, а не список?

Comment: Тогда `text` должен быть не списком, а словарём. А потом просто `text['filename'] = file.readlines()`.

Comment: Добавил картинку так должно быть понятнее.

Comment: всеравно не ясно. превидите результат который требуется

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что получится словарь, где ключом будет название файла, а значением -- список его строк?

Comment: @gil9red правильно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
text = {
    'file_1.txt': [],
    'file_2.txt': []
}

for file_name in text:
    with open(file_name, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        text[file_name] = [*map(str.strip, file.readlines())]

print(text)
```

Comment: А `[*map(str.strip, file.readlines())]` случаем не тоже самое что `list(map(str.strip, file.readlines()))`? Кст, ваш код рабочий, но могут возникнуть проблемы, если в строках слева или справа есть пробелы (или символы табуляции) -- они будут убраны, поэтому одним из вариантов будет использование `rstrip` с заданным параметром `\r\n` или использование другой метод получения строк, а именно: `text[file_name] = file.read().splitlines()`

Comment: @gil9red, абсолютно, просто мне так удобней. По поводу стрипа согласен, но честно говоря, давайте отталкиваться от "ТЗ". Ни одного пробела ни в конце ни в начале ни в середине я не увидел. Можно предположить множество вариантов, но "защиту от дурака" писать в элементарном коде который нужен всего-лишь для того, чтобы продемонстрировать принцип, не вижу смысла

Comment: Впервые увидел `[*map(...)]` необычно, но интересно :) Согласен насчет излишней перестраховки, она лишняя, но мне кажется, что `file.read().splitlines()` выглядит проще :)

Comment: @gil9red, чисто на ассоциативном уровне, мне эта конструкция больше нравится, квадратные скобки в коде видно лучше чем `list()`